# Dotnet core: calling Powershell module does not provide output

Tags: c#, powershell, module, .net-core

I am writing a DOTNET core 2.0 console application that will receive a powershell command and execute it on that system and return the results (to the console for now).

The code sample below is a stripped down version of what I am trying to accomplish. Using this code, if I execute the command **dotnet run "get-childitem**" I get the following response:

```
 [x] Received get-childitem
    Directory: C:\git\campus-database-services
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         4/3/2018   3:18 PM                .vscode
d-----        4/17/2018   8:58 PM                bin
d-----        4/17/2018   8:58 PM                obj
-a----         4/3/2018   3:18 PM              9 .gitignore
-a----         4/3/2018   3:18 PM            211 AppSettings.json
-a----        4/20/2018  10:29 AM            763 campus-database-services.cs
-a----        4/17/2018   8:55 PM           1091 campus-database-services.csproj
-a----         4/8/2018   8:17 AM            392 nuget.config
 [x] Done get-childitem
```

---

However, when I execute the command **dotnet run "Get-DbaSqlService"**, I get the following output:

```
 [x] Received Get-DbaSqlService
 [x] Done Get-DbaSqlService
```

This is a powershell module found at http://dbatools.io - a very standard SQL Server community driven powershell module. This module works great on my system. When invoked on my machine, it will return a list of all installed SQL Server services. This is a very simple example of calling a Powershell module that is installed on the system. In the case that I call a Powershell module, I get no results as seen above - no output of the command at all. I can do the same with calling any function found in any Powershell module.
However, if I call any native command such as **get-childitem**, **get-process**, or **get-service**, the return results work just fine. Whenever I call a function from an installed module, I do not get an error, just no results.

The intent of this application is to pass in commands and it will execute them and return the results. In this case, it appears that the powershell command never executed or returned results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to this and it seems very trivial. However, I am very stuck and have been for quite some time.

---

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Net;
class MyApp
{
    public static void Main(string[] message)
    {    
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message[0]);
        var shell = PowerShell.Create();
        shell.Commands.AddScript(message[0] + " | out-string");
        var results = shell.Invoke();
        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var psObject in results)
            {
                builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Done {0}", message[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?  Is the SQL module installed in the `$Env:PSModulePath`?

Comment: Powershell version 5.1

Comment: The module is the in the PSModulePath. I can also call that command directly from the command-line without any issues. I can open powershell and execute that command with the proper output every time. When I call my C# application and pass in that command (or from any module) I always get no response (or error). My understanding is that if it could not find the module or function, it would return an error.

Comment: I can execute **dotnet run "get-process;get-childitem"** and get a list of all processes and then a list of the current directory (multiple commands). However, if I issue the command **dotnet run "import-module dbatools;Get-DbaSqlService"** it does not return anything.

Comment: Maybe if there is a way to return the error stream I can find out what is going on. I have no idea how that can be accomplished. Any ideas??

Comment: It is looking more like that I am expecting Powershell 5.1 but my .NET core application is targeting Powershell core 6. It looks like it is impossible for DOTNET core to reference Powershell 5.1. If anyone has any information to the contrary I would love to hear it!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using core if you're only running your app on a Windows box?

Comment: That is a good question. I was looking to have the option to run it on Windows, Mac, or Linux as needed. I also hoped to use the most current version of .NET which I was under the assumption was DOTNET Core. I think that I might have to start over and use .NET instead as I believe that I can only target PowerShell  core using DOTNET core and the modules that I am using cannot work in PowerShell Core. If I cannot run a DOTNET Core C# application and target Powershell 5.1 then that is not an option.

Comment: I guess another reason is easily using Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio (which I do not own and copy and work in an Enterprise shop. I am having trouble finding out how to create a console app targeting .NET (not DOTNET core) using VSCode.

Comment: While exploring the help dialogues, you can specify netstandard2.0 as a framework for classlib, but it doesn't appear you can do that with console apps.  This can be edited in the `App.csproj` file. Additionally, build options can be manually edited in `project.assets.json`